# How to animate(shrink and Expand) to array of UIButtons

Tags: ios

I have to perform shrink and expand animation for array of UIButtons. For single UIButton I am doing like this...

```
 UIButton *button = [self.destinationButtonsArray objectAtIndex:0];
 [UIView beginAnimations:@"shrink" context:(__bridge void *)(button)];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse |                UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction  animations:^{

        [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:3];

        CGAffineTransform t  = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2f, 1.2f);
        button.transform = t;


    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);}];
```

How can i achieve same effect for array of UIbutons.

Comment: Did you see issues when you put the code in a for loop?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a `for` inside the animation block, something like:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"shrink" context:(__bridge void *)(button)];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse |                            UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat |     UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction  animations:^{

    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:3];

    CGAffineTransform t  = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2f, 1.2f);

    for (UIButton button in self.destinationButtonsArray) {
        button.transform = t;
    }
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    for (UIButton button in self.destinationButtonsArray) {
        button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);}];
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of category. Declare a `UIButton` category and add method to perform the animation.

**UIButton+Transform.h**

```
@interface UIButton (Transform)

- (void) applyAnimation;

@end
```

**UIButton+Transform.m**

```
@implementation UIButton (Transform)

- (void) applyAnimation {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"shrink" context:self];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                                | UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                                | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                                | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
            animations:^{
                     [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
                    CGAffineTransform t  = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2f, 1.2f);
                    self.transform = t;
            }
            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
            }
     ];
}

@end
```

Call the method on the array as follows

```
[self.destinationButtonsArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(applyAnimation)];
```

This will call the animation method on all buttons in the array.

Hope that helps!